# UNION ALL is returning multiple results

Tags: mysql, sql

This query is returning multiple results.  In the bottom you can see there are two of each id number.  How do I distinct records where I still get 25 records of unique values?

```
        SELECT *
            FROM(
                SELECT
                    DISTINCT cards.id, cards.name, cards.created_at, cards.updated_at
                    FROM cards
                        INNER JOIN card_process
                            ON card_process.card_id = cards.id
                            INNER JOIN processes
                                ON processes.id = card_process.process_id
                                INNER JOIN category_process
                                    ON category_process.process_id = processes.id
                                    INNER JOIN categories
                                        ON categories.id = category_process.category_id
                                        INNER JOIN series
                                            ON series.id = categories.serie_id
                                            INNER JOIN serie_user
                                                ON serie_user.serie_id = series.id
                        AND `cards`.`type` NOT IN ('', 'libraries')
                        AND NOT `cards`.`deleted`
                        AND NOT `categories`.`deleted`
                        AND NOT `series`.`deleted`
                        AND `cards`.`type` IN ('forms')
                        AND `series`.`id` IN (124,235,126,126,201,236,207,207,207,207,247,234,131,131,221,225,225,222)
            UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    DISTINCT cards.id, cards.name, cards.created_at, cards.updated_at
                    FROM cards
                        WHERE `cards`.`account_user_id`='9'
                            AND NOT `cards`.`deleted`
                            AND `cards`.`type` IN ('forms')
            ) AS qry
                ORDER BY `updated_at` ASC
                LIMIT 0, 25
```

[image]

Comment: Use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not knowing anything about your schema or the shape of your data, you can get what you want by simplifying your query. Assuming a roughly standard-compliant SQL dialect

- You don't need the enclosing `select`. A *full select* (unioned select expression) takes `order by` and that order by applies to the entire *full select*.
- You don't need the `distinct` keyword on the individual `select` statements in the `union`: `union` by itself eliminates duplicate rows.

And please, when you write a long complicated query, spend some time formatting it so the next sod (who might be you a few years hence) who has to comprehend it can do so easily.

That gets you to the equivalent:

```
SELECT cards.id   ,
       cards.name ,
       cards.created_at ,
       cards.updated_at
FROM       cards
INNER JOIN card_process     ON card_process.card_id = cards.id
INNER JOIN processes        ON processes.id = card_process.process_id
INNER JOIN category_process ON category_process.process_id = processes.id
INNER JOIN categories       ON categories.id =  category_process.category_id
INNER JOIN series           ON series.id = categories.serie_id
INNER JOIN serie_user       ON serie_user.serie_id = series.id
                           AND `cards`.`type` NOT IN ('', 'libraries')
                           AND NOT `cards`.`deleted`
                           AND NOT `categories`.`deleted`
                           AND NOT `series`.`deleted`
                           AND `cards`.`type` IN ('forms')
                           AND `series`.`id` IN (124,235,126,126,201,236,207,207,207,207,247,234,131,131,221,225,225,222)
UNION
SELECT cards.id   ,
       cards.name ,
       cards.created_at ,
       cards.updated_at
FROM cards
WHERE `cards`.`account_user_id`='9'
  AND NOT `cards`.`deleted`
  AND `cards`.`type` IN ('forms')
ORDER BY `updated_at` ASC
LIMIT 0, 25
```

If MySql doesn't allow limit on a *full select*, then you might need the enclosing `select` statement.

**Also, one might note that your join criteria is almost certainly incorrect.** In the 1st select, the join criteria for the table `serie_user` has a bunch of tests:

```
AND `cards`.`type` NOT IN ('', 'libraries')
AND NOT `cards`.`deleted`
AND NOT `categories`.`deleted`
AND NOT `series`.`deleted`
AND `cards`.`type` IN ('forms')
AND `series`.`id` IN (124,235,126,126,201,236,207,207,207,207,247,234,131,131,221,225,225,222)
```

They **only** apply to joining in the candidate rows from `serie_user`. They don't apply to the result set as a whole. They should be refactored into a `where` clause and into the join criteria for the pertinent tables, thus:

```
SELECT cards.id   ,
       cards.name ,
       cards.created_at ,
       cards.updated_at
FROM       cards
INNER JOIN card_process     ON card_process.card_id        = cards.id
INNER JOIN processes        ON processes.id                = card_process.process_id
INNER JOIN category_process ON category_process.process_id = processes.id
INNER JOIN categories       ON categories.id               =  category_process.category_id
                           AND NOT `categories`.`deleted`
INNER JOIN series           ON series.id                   = categories.serie_id
                           AND NOT `series`.`deleted`
                           AND     `series`.`id`           IN (124,235,126,126,201,236,207,207,207,207,247,234,131,131,221,225,225,222)
INNER JOIN serie_user       ON serie_user.serie_id         = series.id
WHERE `cards`.`type` NOT IN ('', 'libraries')
  AND NOT `cards`.`deleted`
  AND     `cards`.`type` IN ('forms')
UNION
SELECT cards.id   ,
       cards.name ,
       cards.created_at ,
       cards.updated_at
FROM cards
WHERE     `cards`.`account_user_id` = '9'
  AND NOT `cards`.`deleted`
  AND     `cards`.`type` IN ('forms')
ORDER BY `updated_at` ASC
LIMIT 0, 25
```

The last thing I want to note is that you are joining in a whole raft of tables that aren't used in the result set. All you're doing is getting a subset of rows from the `cards` table. That suggests to me that you're likely better off if you simply got rid of the `union` and all the extraneous joins and simply asked the right question.

That eliminates the possibility of duplicates completely.

A little refactoring gets it down to this (no guarantee I've got it 100% correct, but you should be able to get the gist of it):

```
select c.id         ,
       c.name       ,
       c.created_at ,
       c.updated_at
from cards c
where   not c.deleted
  and       c.type            = 'forms'
  and (     c.account_user_id = '9'
        OR exists ( select *
                    from card_process     cp
                    join processes        p   on     p.id           = cp.process_id
                    join category_process cpx on     cpx.process_id = p.id
                    join categories       c   on     c.id           = cpx.category_id
                                             and not c.deleted
                    join series           s   on     s.id           = categories.serid_id
                                             and not s.deleted
                                             and     series.id IN ( 124 , 235 , 126 , ... )
                    join serie_user       su  on     su.serid_id     = s.id
                    where cp.card_id = c.card_id
                  )
      )
ORDER BY updated_at
LIMIT 0, 25
```

There's often a simple query hidden inside a complex one.

Comment: Interesting formatting style. Drives me crazy, personally, but I can definitely see why you would implore it.

Comment: @beeks: SQL syntax is bad enough. And when queries get complicated you need to be be able to grok it. The O.P. nested join layout is a code smell indicating procedural thinking (nested loops) rather than thanking in terms of sets, relational algebra and predicate calculus. Further, a lot of cognitive research shows that a regular, tabular layout enhances understanding. People grok tables.

Comment: @Nicolas Carey, I do agree. The OP's code is a mess, I would avoid all T-SQL like that myself. But your formatting is interesting, but drives me up the wall.

To each ones own though.

Comment: Wow that awesome! Normally I use an ORM for all database interactions, do you have a style guide for SQL? The query above was from the style of someone else on SO I just picked up.

Comment: From wikipedia `Transact-SQL (T-SQL) is Microsoft's and Sybase's proprietary`... oh god damn it...

Comment: There's nothing specific to T-SQL in what I wrote. With the exception of the `limit` clause, it's all vanilla, standard SQL that should work on any reasonably standards-compliant implementation of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's how `UNION ALL` works, it simply gives you all the rows of both your queries.

If you want to remove duplicates, use `UNION`  , without the `ALL` part.

Comment: You can also make it explicit with `UNION DISTINCT`.

Comment: `UNION ALL` to `UNION` fixed it just can't accept for another 10 min.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not seeing a difference in my result set with or without the `UNION DISTINCT`

Comment: `UNION` and `UNION DISTINCT` are the same, they both remove duplicates. `UNION ALL` leaves duplicates.